# Using JQuery to get table values

Tags: jquery

I have a html table with 4 tablecells:
1: Checkbox
2. label
3. textbox
4. label

Once I click on the checkbox, a jquery function fires, but im trying to get the values next to the checkbox. I have tried below, but nothing works. I know I am close. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
$(this).next()
$(this).nextSibling
$(this).nextSibling.childNodes[0]


 <table id="MainContent_cockpitTable" style="width:80%;">
  <tr>
<td>
      <input id="MainContent_check_FLIGHT DECK1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>    
    </td>
     <td>Pilot</td>
     <td><input "type="text" value="86.2" maxlength="10" id="MainContent_input_FLIGHT DECK_weight1" />
     </td>
     <td><span id="MainContent_input_FLIGHT DECK_arm1" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">255.0</span></td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: could you post your html code, might be easier to follow.

Comment: Values next to the checkbox?

Comment: my answer will work - i kind of guessed your html and got it right

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the text input when the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/suSkb/

**Your case specific demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7nyn8/

Please note: `classes` can have spaces but not `id` and `id` should be unique.

Hope it fits your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$('.hulk').click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).parents('tr').html());
     alert('Lable HTML = > ' + $(this).parents('tr').find('lable').text())   
});
​
```

**further**

```
$('.hulk').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents('tr').html());
    alert('Pilot here:=> ' + $(this).parent().next().html());
    alert('Lable HTML = > ' + $(this).parents('tr').find('span').text())
});​
```

Comment: I just guessed , that when he said label he meant plain text , I think you and some other answer thought he knew what he said when he said label

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('label').text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jnTF/2/

Comment: Why not +1, no one is upvoting today `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).next('td').html();
```

or

```
$(this).next('td').text();
```

This should work - ( i think ) that you have something like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type=checkbox .... /> </td>
    <td> YOU WANT THIS LABEL </td>
    <td> <input type=textbox ..... /> </td>
    <td> ANOTHER LABEL </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not +1, no one is upvoting today `:)`